# Microsoft-Cognitive topic detection issue

Tags: r, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use the topic detection API from Microsoft_cognitive through R and is not working ('mscstexta4r' package, I provided the key to it). My subscription is through my university and I'm using my laptop at home. Could that be the reason of the problem?

Specifically, the error I'm getting is 'Error: mscstexta4r: Not Found (HTTP 404). - { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }'

Please see attached screenshot of my R console. The stoplist that I'm using is a customized one and the data has 760 '.txt' documents of no more than 5KB each one (the total is 225KB[Screenshot of R console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivT6R.png))

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a typo in the URL.

```
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text**a**/analytics/v2.0/
```

To submit a job the POST URL should be:

```
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/topics
```

To query for the job status, it’s a GET request to:

```
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/operations/{operationId}
```

See the [Text Analytics API reference](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3ca) for more details about the parameters.

Comment: Sorry Assaf, but that doesn't work. The URL that I'm using is the one specified in the R package documentation: textanalyticsurl": "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/texta/analytics/v2.0/ But I tried other possible combinations, just in case

Comment: I'm not sure what R package you're referring too, but the URL for MS Text Analytics service is not the one you specified. You're getting a 404 which means unknown URL. Have you tried making a post request to the URL above? Did you get the same or different error?